# How to join the value of cells of a column, but only if a condition based in an other column is met

Tags: openrefine

In record mode, is it possible to join the value of cells of a column, but only if a condition based in an other column is met ?

Example : 
With those data, in each record, join the values in col3 only for the rows where col2="yes"

[image]

Expected result :

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution in Python/Jython:

```
col2 = row.record.cells.col2.value
col3 = row.record.cells.col3.value

return ";".join([x for x,j in zip(col3,col2) if j == "yes"])
```

[image]

For Grel, the best solution is probably something like this (if you like russian dolls):

```
forEachIndex(row.record.cells.col3.value, i, v, if(row.record.cells.col2.value[i]=="yes", v, null)).join(";")
```

**It is also possible to do that without formulas:**

- Switch to row mode
- Text facet on col2, select the "yes".
- On col3 (or a copy of col3): Edit cells / Join multivalued cells
- On col3 again (or your copy of col3): Edit cells / Fill down

Comment: Thansk ! I tried with forEachIndex() too but massive headache!